# Why must complex linear maps be of the form $h \mapsto ah$, $a \in \mathbb{C}$?

Tags: complex-analysis

On page 4 of David Ullrich's "Complex Made Simple", he says that complex linear maps from $\mathbb{C}$ to $\mathbb{C}$ are precisely of the form $h \mapsto ah$ for some complex number $a$.

How do I prove that all complex linear maps must be of this form (multiplication by a complex number)?

Comment: If you show us what you have tried perhaps someone can use what you know to provide a useful hint or answer.

Comment: $f(h)=f(h\cdot 1) = h f(1)$.

Comment: What's your definition of _linear_? It follows pretty quickly from that.

Comment: David Ullrich does **not** say that, @Jean Valjean (Ah, les Miserables...!), but he talks of $\;\Bbb C-linear\;$ complex maps... **very different!**  And this much is true for any one dimension vector space $\;C\;$ over any field $\;\Bbb F\;$ : the only $\;\Bbb F-$linear maps of $\;V\;$ are of the form $\;v\mapsto rv\;,\;\;r\in\Bbb F\;$ .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $\varphi$ is a complex linear map from $\mathbb{C}$ to $\mathbb{C}$, and $z$ is a given complex number, we see that

$$\varphi(z) = \varphi(z \cdot 1) = z \varphi(1)$$

by linearity. Set $a = \varphi(1)$.

Comment: Thanks. Looks like my confusion was that I am so used to the concept of a real vector space linear map where you can only pull out the scalar, $T(av) = aT(v)$, that I completely overlooked that in this case, the complex number input is also a scalar that can be pulled out! i.e. $T(vw) = vT(w) = wT(v)$ for any complex numbers $v,w$.

Comment: One potentially-useful way of viewing this, incidentally, is as the special case of a canonical isomorphism from $GL_1(\mathcal{F})$ to $\mathcal{F}$ for any field $\mathcal{F}$.